# UITableViewController tintColor

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am trying to setTintColor for a viewcontroller that inherits from a UITableViewController.

I tried to put

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

as the last line in loadView, but the color doesn't change. Where should I make this change?

Here is the interface definition of the controller:

```
@interface MyViewController : UITableViewController 
{
    Model *model;

    NSArray * calculators;
}
@end
```

UPDATE: I finally put it in viewDidAppear and it worked.

Comment: Try placing it in `viewDidLoad` instead.

Comment: @BoltClock. Tried, didn't work.

Comment: Since you are settings black as the tint color, you might want to change the bar style instead, i.e. `self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;`. I would put this in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Is your table view controller actually in a navigation controller, or do you create a navigation bar separately?

Comment: @BoltClock: Check my definition of UIViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put my solution in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your self.navigationController is not nil? This is a usual bug happenning all the time that you didn't present your `MyViewController` with a navigationController

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Comment: What's the difference between that and using `setTintColor:`?

Comment: Yeah, it's exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
}
```